Does length of key have an any impact on performance in Azure Keyvalut?
Does having a long key in Azure Keyvault affect in any way the performance taking into consideration that data might be added to Keyvault in very large volumes? (hundreds of entries daily)

In Azure Key Vault, long keys can affect performance, potentially increasing latency and causing throttling. Moreover, managing numerous resource versions can impact backup operations. Therefore, it's crucial to manage key lengths and resource versions judiciously to ensure optimal performance. @jayanthkulkarni
